# Sulu update 1.6 > 2.0 - we_analytics

Tags: sulu

We're currently upgrading sulu 1.6. to 2.0 - while following [the guide](https://docs.sulu.io/en/2.0/upgrades/upgrade-1.6-2.0.html) I noticed, that we_analytics.title stays on varchar(255), while all other varchar fields are converted to varchar(191)

```sql
ALTER TABLE we_analytics CHANGE webspace_key webspace_key VARCHAR(191) NOT NULL;
-- this one is missing?: ALTER TABLE we_analytics CHANGE title title VARCHAR(191) NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE we_analytics CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Is this an error of the docs or correct like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an error in the upgrade guide, if at all the problem is within the [ORM configuration itself](https://github.com/sulu/sulu/blob/7d054ca/src/Sulu/Bundle/WebsiteBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/Analytics.orm.xml#L16).

However, this does not matter too much here anyway, because the 191 character limit only applies on index fields in MySQL, so this continues to work. We will only run into troubles when we decide to put an index on that field.